# Uniqueness quantification and injection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Definition of uniqueness is $\exists y [P(y) \land \forall x[P(x) \rightarrow x=y]]$. Then, $\exists y [P(y) \land \forall x[\lnot P(x) \lor x=y]]$. Distributing $P(y)$, we have $\exists y \forall x[[P(y) \land \lnot P(x)] \lor [P(y) \land (x=y)]]$. So, we have $\exists y \forall x[[P(y) \rightarrow P(x)] \rightarrow P(y) \land (x=y)]$, then $\exists y \forall x[[P(y) \rightarrow P(x)] \rightarrow x=y] \land [[P(y) \rightarrow P(x)] \rightarrow P(y)]$ and, finally, $\exists y \forall x[[[P(y) \rightarrow P(x)] \rightarrow x=y] \land  P(y)]$.

Now, if we consider $P(x)=z \in f(x)$, being $f$ a function, we have: $\exists y \forall x[[[z \in f(y) \rightarrow z \in f(x)] \rightarrow x=y] \land  z \in f(y)]$. If we universally generalize $z$, we come up with $\exists y \forall x [[f(y) \subseteq f(x) \rightarrow x=y] \land  z \in f(y)]$.

Since $f(y) \subseteq f(x) \rightarrow y \subseteq x$ is the definition of injection, is it correct to say that uniqueness implies injectivity?

Comment: How you moved from $\land$ to $\subseteq$ ?

Comment: "P(y) subset P(x)" and "x subset y" are nonsensical.

Comment: Mr Allegranza: the negation of $P(y) \land \lnot P(x)$ is $P(y) \rightarrow P(x)$. Since x is universally instantiated, we can say $P(y) \subseteq P(x)$. Mr Elliot: thanks, it was a typo. I meant $P(y) \subseteq P(x) \rightarrow y \subseteq x$

Comment: *I mean, universally quantified.

Comment: And how about if I substitute P(x) for an elementhood test and then generalize it? I did the proper changes in the original post.

Comment: The third line is a blunder and lacks parentheses.

Comment: Mr Elliot, you mean this one $\exists y \forall x[P(y) \land \lnot P(x) \lor P(y) \land (x=y)]$? I don't see any mistake here. The $\land$ operator can distribute over the universal quantification $\forall$, since this last one is in fact an expansion of conjunctions. Therefore, $P(y) \land \forall x P(x)$ is equivalent to $\forall x P(y) \land P(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

- There is a link between uniqueness and injectivity.
- A function $f $ from $A$ to $B$ is said to be *injective* iff

for all $y$ belonging to $B$

**[** IF   **(** there is some $x$ (belonging to A) which is the preimage of $y$ **)**

THEN  **(** $x$ is the unique preimage of $y$**)** **]**.

The last line could be phrased more formally

... then ( for all $z$, ($f(z)= y$) $\rightarrow$ ($z = x$) )

So, unicity of $x$ amounts to this:

***in case there is some x such that*** $f(x)=y$ , any object $z$ has to be identical to $x$ in order to have $y$ as image.

Note that, here, the existence of $x$ is not asserted absolutely, but ***hypothetically*** ( " in case..." ). If you prefer: in case there is some $x$ having the property of being a preimage of $y$, then, $x$ is the unique preimage of $y$.

- In terms of ordered pairs, one could also say that a function $f$ is injective iff there are  no two ordered pairs belonging to $f$

  (1)  that have the same second element

  (2) but different first elements.